# How to use 'input' to input mathematical functions as variables in python 3.x

Tags: python, numpy, input

I want the user of my program to input a mathematical function of their choosing in numpy notation so that I can operate on it. For example:

```
import numpy as np
f=eval(input("Please input your function in numpy notation")

>>> "Please input your function in numpy notation"
>>> np.exp(x)
>>> NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

with the code above, the user is inputting the exponential function, which is saved to a variable 'f' - more generally, I would like any mathematical function to be given as input and for it to be stored somehow as a python function. Pseudocode for this may be something like:

```
def F(x):
    f = eval(input("Please enter function in numpy notation:"))
    return f
```

which, if we use the exponential function again as an example, would be equivalent to hard coding:

```
def F(x):
    return np.exp(x)
```

One more example for clarity.

```
def F(x):
    f = eval(input("Please enter function in numpy notation:"))
    return f

>>> x*np.sin(x)
```

The user input x*np.sin(x) on the command line, which is equivalent to hard coding:

```
def F(x):
    return x*np.sin(x)
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: [You do not want to use `eval()`](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). Whenever you reach a point where you need to execute arbitrary input from an external source it's time to re-think your strategy and goals.

Comment: What about `eval("os.system('rm -rf /')")` ?-)

Comment: @zwer  So as the purpose of a terminal would be to execute arbitrary input from an external source, from your point of view terminals shoudln't exist ? I think there's some context missing as to how to program is intended to be used to really judge on those kind of question ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr).

Example:

```
In [23]: import numexpr as ne

In [24]: a = np.arange(1e6)

In [25]: s = "sin(a)**2 + cos(a)**2"

In [27]: res = ne.evaluate(s)

In [28]: res
Out[28]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.])

In [29]: res.shape
Out[29]: (1000000,)
```

it's also often faster than Numpy:

```
In [32]: %timeit ne.evaluate(s)
11.4 ms ± 256 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [33]: %timeit np.sin(a)**2 + np.cos(a)**2
41 ms ± 1.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would we to just wrap `eval` in a function and give it access to the names `x` and `np`:

```
import numpy

i = input("fn: ")  # enter function once

def f(x):
    return eval(i, {'x': x, 'np': numpy})

f(42)  # call it
f(0)  # call it again...
```

Note that `eval` is highly unsafe. Nothing prevents the user from entering evil code. If you care a tad bit about safety (or performance), @MaxU's answer is preferable.

If you plan to call the function often, it makes sense to pre-compile it:

```
i = input("fn: ")  # enter function once
i = compile(i, 'input', 'eval')
```

The resulting code object can be passed to `eval` just like a string.

Timing the input `np.exp(x)`:

```
%timeit f(0.5)  # Without pre-compilation
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 14.2 µs per loop

%timeit f(0.5)  # With pre-compilation
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `f = eval(input("Please enter function in numpy notation:"))` The input by the user gets interpreted as if you had written it in your file. So if your user inputs `x+1` then your python script will try to do `x+1` in that line.

If you want that line to create a function your user will have to enter something that evaluates to an actual function. That could be something like `lambda x: x+1` which returns a function with one argument (x), calculating `x+1`. Of course you could also add the `lambda x:` in your code. Small Example:

```
def F(x):
    return eval("lambda x:" + input("Please input a function in numpy notation!"))

x = 1
f = F(x)
print(f(x))
```

Of course this will require that the variable is always called `x`.

If you execute above code and enter e.g. `x+1` the output is 2.

Comment: what if the function was cos or sin? how would we implement a library?